# JRE6 compatibility issue with the BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

My code works with jre7 and not jre6. Is there a possibility to make it compatible with jre6:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

Eclipse prompts an error stating:

```
The resource type BufferedReader does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable
```

Could you explain the problem here? What is the solution? Thanks

Comment: You're encountering the try-with-resources java 7 feature. Read the [tutorial article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) that describes it and how to work around it.

Comment: one more article for easy understanding http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/back-to-basics-java-7-autocloseable-tutorial-overview/.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the new `try` construct with the classic `finally` clause:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
try {

} catch(IOException e) {

} finally {
   br.close();
}
```

This will close the reader in any case, also if an exception has been thrown from the inside try block. Only [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) classes can be used in try-with-resources construct, and java 6 `BufferedReader` is not (java 7 `BufferedReader` is).

Answer (score 1):

You as using the try-with-resources statement. All objects implementing java.lang.AutoCloseable can be used as a resource. BufferedReader is not extending from AutoCloseble in Java 6. That's why you are seeing this error.

There is a good tutorial explaining the difference [here](https://www.stackstalk.com/2014/05/java-7-try-with-resources.html).

Answer (score 1):

the below code uses `try` with resource of type `AutoClosable`

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

which is the feature added in Java7, so it works well in Java7.

but same will not work in Java 6 or below.

Java 6 or below support simple try without autoclose type resource.

so your code should be like below in java 6

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
try{
//do whatever you want

} catch(IOException e) {

}
```